# How to use discord.PartialEmoji/discord.Emoji object?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, emoji

I need to get an emoji as an emoji object for reaction roles but i whatever i do i ether get the error

> discord.ext.commands.errors.PartialEmojiConversionFailure: Couldn't convert " " to PartialEmoji.

if i am using discord.PartialEmoji or

> discord.ext.commands.errors.EmojiNotFound: Emoji " " not found.

if i am using discord.Eomji.

Example Code where these errors happen

```
@commands.command() 
async def test(self,ctx,emoji: discord.Emoji = None): 
    await ctx.send(emoji)
```

Edit:

At first the reaction role should be created like this:

```
@commands.command() 
async def reactionrole(self,ctx,msgid: int = None,emoji: discord.Emoji = None , role: discord.Role = None ): 
    
    
    if msgid is None:
        await ctx.send('Use the following template to create reactionroles (ex. treactionrole <#messageid> <emoji> <@role>)')
    elif emoji is None:
        await ctx.send('Use the following template to create reactionroles (ex. treactionrole <#messageid> <emoji> <@role>)')
    elif role is None:
        await ctx.send('Use the following template to create reactionroles (ex. treactionrole <#messageid> <emoji> <@role>)')
    else:
        if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_roles:
                    db = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
                    cursor = db.cursor() 
                    sql = ("INSERT INTO reaction_role(message_id,emoji,role) VALUES(?,?,?)")

                    val = (msgid,emoji,str(role))
                    msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(int(msgid))
                    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
                    cursor.execute(sql,val)
                    db.commit()
                    cursor.close()
                    db.close()
        else:
            await ctx.author.send('You dont have the permission to use reactionroles on this Server!')
```

Then if an reaction happens an method should get the message out of the db where the msgid and the emoji is the same as the reacted one like this:

```
async def reaction_roles_role(msgid,emoji):
        db = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT role FROM reaction_role WHERE message_id = {msgid} and emoji = {emoji}")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using default emojis for this or Emojis from other servers? Because discord.Emoji only works with custom Emojis from servers with your bot on it.

If you wanna get all of these you have to do something like this:

```
@commands.command() 
async def test(self, ctx, emoji): 
    print(str(emoji))
```

And for reaction roles you could compare in `on_raw_reaction_add` like this:

```
if str(payload.emoji) == str(your_emoji_here):
```

Comment: I am using both, default and server-specific emojis but I need the emoji as an object to reach the url as example So that if there are several Reactionroles on one message I can distinguish them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you edit your question with the reaction event you are using?

Comment: yes i edited it

Comment: I'm not sure what your `reaction_roles_role` function does. Do you have a `on_reaction_add` or `on_raw_reaction_add` listener set up? Other than that you should convert the emoji to a string before adding it to the database. And in your listener you should do the same before comparing them. That will work with any emojis